# How to show an message box from terminal in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu-gnome

I want to show an message box from terminal in Ubuntu, I have GNOME 3 desktop environment.

How should I proceed?

Comment: short answer is  `zenity`. Use `man zenity ` for more  information.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

### Using `zenity`:

```
sudo lsof | tee >(zenity --progress --pulsate) > out
```

[image]

---

```
zenity --question --text "Are you sure you want to shutdown?"; echo $?
```

[image]

---

```
zenity --warning --text "This will kill, are you sure?";echo $?
```

[image]

---

```
ans=$(zenity --scale --text "pick a number" --min-value=2 --max-value=100 --value=2 --step 2); echo "$ans"
```

[image]

---

```
sudo lsof | zenity --text-info --width 530
```

[image]

---

---

### Using `yad`

Install `yad`

```
sudo apt-add repository ppa:webupd8team/y-ppa-manager
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install yad
```

Create a example script `example` and add the lines below

```
#!/bin/bash
frmdata=$(yad --title "Test Form" --form --field "Address" --field="Name")

frmaddr=$(echo "$frmdata" | awk 'BEGIN {FS="|" } { print $1 }')
frmname=$(echo "$frmdata" | awk 'BEGIN {FS="|" } { print $2 }')

echo "$frmaddr" 
echo "$frmname"
```

[image]

---

Or more complex:

```
yad --width=400 --title="" --text="Please enter your details:" \
--image="/usr/share/icons/Tango/scalable/emotes/face-smile.svg" \
--form --date-format="%-d %B %Y" --item-separator="," \
--field="Last name" \
--field="First name" \
--field="Date of birth":DT \
--field="Last holiday":CBE \
"" "" "Click calendar icon" "Gold Coast, Bali,Phuket, Sydney, other"
```

[image]

---

### Using `notify-send`

```
notify-send "Hello" "Hello world"
```

[image]

### Using `dialog`

```
dialog --msgbox "Hello world" 10 30
```

[image]

---

### Using `whiptail`

```
whiptail --msgbox "Hello world" 10 30
```

[image]

Comment: Cannot resist upvoting this nice overview :) +1

Comment: +1 I like too kinda fun also ;)

Comment: @WhiteStone As you're a reputation 1 user: If this answer helped you, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of this text, which means "yes, this answer is valid"! ;-)